# Call to a member function tasks() on null on laravel 5.4 adding a new task

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

my TaskController.php look like this

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);

        //dd($request->name);

        $request->user()->tasks()->create([
            'name' => $request->name,
        ]);

        return redirect('/tasks');
    }

and Task.php look like

 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

(1/1) FatalErrorException Call to a member function tasks() on null

Comment: Where are you getting the user that you are assigning the task? **$user = User::find($id)**, and then you could use the **task()** method, for example, **$user->tasks()->create([ 'name' => $request->name,]);**

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
Task::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'your_user_id_fieldname_goes_here'=> 'value goes here'
]);
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: u mean   $request->user()->Task::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
        ]); i tried Task::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
        ]); but it end up with error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `tasks` (`name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (sdfsadf, 2017-10-26 09:02:15, 2017-10-26 09:02:15))

Comment: No Just Task::create([ 'name' => $request->name, ]); 
No need of `$request->user()->`

Comment: Tasks table contain user_id field

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a relationship between the tasks and the users within the users model class ? from what I can tell you might have missed to add it.

Comment: Task.php  public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

Comment: user.php     public function tasks()
    {

        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

Comment: ok are you sure that `$request->user()` has the user object ? as from the error message its look like the result of `$request->user()` is null